# differential equation $y^{\prime} = ky$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the equation:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} = -0.04\sqrt{y}
\end{align*}

I had moved $\mathrm{d}t$ to the other side as well as $\sqrt{y}$ and took the integral on each side. I came to the equation
\begin{align*}
y = \left(\frac{-0.04t + c}{2}\right)^2
\end{align*}

But I am not sure this is correct and if c would just be y(0).

Comment: $c$ may not necessarily be equal to $y(0)$.  If you plug in $t=0$, you get an equation for $c$ in terms of $y(0)$, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not actually sure which DE you want solved, so I'll solve both.

Number 1:
$$f'(x)=kf(x)$$
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=k$$
$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=k\int dx$$
Let $y=f(x)$. Therefore $dy=f'(x)dx$
$$\int\frac{dy}{y}=kx+c$$
$$\ln|y|=kx+c$$
$$f(x)=e^{kx+c}$$
Number 2:
$$f'(x)=k\sqrt{f(x)}$$
$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{f(x)}}dx=kx+c$$
$$\int\frac{dy}{y^{1/2}}=kx+c$$
$$2y^{1/2}=kx+c$$
$$f(x)=\Biggl(\frac{kx+c}{2}\Biggr)^2$$
Plug in the constants and you're good to go.

Edit:
For the second one: $$f(a)=b$$
$$\Biggl(\frac{ka+c}{2}\Biggr)^2=b$$
$$b^{1/2}=\frac{ka+c}{2}$$
$$ka+c=2\sqrt{b}$$
$$c=2\sqrt{b}-ka$$

Comment: I needed the second equation you did. So I would solve for c, and since im given that y(0)=3, I would end up with 2sqrt(3) = c?

Comment: @Jytrex How about now?

Comment: yes thanks! so if I were to do f(0) =3, ka would = 0, and then have 2sqrt(3)

Comment: @Jytrex If the solution helps, give it a big 'ole check

Comment: sure, and so I am correct in saying the value for c?

Comment: @Jytrex you are spot on. Sorry I didn't answer your question in my last comment

Answer (score 1):

$$\int y^{-\frac12} \, dy = -0.04 \int \, dt $$

$$\frac{\sqrt{y}}{\frac12}=-0.04t+c$$

$$y=\left(\frac{-0.04t+c}{2}\right)^2$$

when $t=0$ , we have $y(0)=\left(\frac{c}2\right)^2$, that is $c = \pm 2\sqrt{y(0)} $

Comment: How do I know whether to use + or minus? I was given y(0)  = 3, and the equation represents water leaving a tank.

Comment: @Jytrex Both are possible according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dy%2Fdt+%3D+0.04sqrt(y),+y(0)%3D3).

Comment: From the second formula you get uniquely $c=2\sqrt{y_0}+0.04t_0$. Note that for $t\ge25c$ you get $y\equiv0$. Any solution $y$ has to be falling by the sign of $y'$ in the ODE.